# Tag Helper - Add all Attributes from a Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have the following tag helper (this is the equivalent of saying Html.Editor):

```
[HtmlTargetElement("editor", Attributes = "for", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class EditorTagHelper : TagHelper {
    private readonly IHtmlHelper _htmlHelper;

    public EditorTagHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
    }

    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, string> HtmlAttributes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public string TemplateName { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> ViewData { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound, ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
        ((IViewContextAware)_htmlHelper).Contextualize(ViewContext);

        ViewData.Add("HtmlAttributes", HtmlAttributes);

        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(_htmlHelper.Editor(For.Name, TemplateName, ViewData));

        output.TagName = null;
    }
}
```

Which is called like so:

```
<editor for="Name" view-data-test="@("Foo")" html-attributes-class="Bar" />
```

Here's the code for the String view template:

```
@model string
<input asp-for="@Model" class="form-control" />
@ViewData["Test"]
@(((IDictionary<string, string>)ViewData["HtmlAttributes"])["Class"])
```

This works fine but ideally I'd like to add the HtmlAttributes dictionary as attributes to the input tag helper above. Previously I would have said the following to pass the attributes to a HTML helper:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { htmlAttributes = ViewData["HtmlAttributes"] })
```

But what is the equivalent to pass them to a tag helper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a tag helper that can work with your Dictionary you'd need to

- supply an attribute on the tag helper class that takes the HTML attributes dictionary
- deconstruct and loop through that dictionary and add it to the output

Start by specifying the `html-attributes` as a HTML attribute to the HtmlTargetElement's comma-separated Attributes list.

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("editor", Attributes = "for, html-attributes", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class EditorTagHelper : TagHelper {
```

Then map those to a property on the tag helper itself:

```cs
[HtmlAttributeName("html-attributes")]
public Dictionary<string, string> HtmlAttributes { get; set; }
```

In the process method, deconstruct and foreach through that dictionary

```cs
foreach (var (key, value) in HtmlAttributes)
{
    output.Attributes.SetAttribute(key, value);
}
```

Use it like:

```cs
<editor for="Name" view-data-test="@("Foo")" html-attributes="@ViewData["HtmlAttributes"]" />
```

**Edit:**

If you want to only pass the ViewData to the template and then apply them to the input element inside you'd need to follow the same procedure as I told you. But you skip applying the htmlAttributes to the Editor element.

```cs
    [HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "for, html-attributes")]
    public class InputTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("html-attributes")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> HtmlAttributes { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context,
            TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagMode = TagMode.SelfClosing;
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("name", EditorFor.Name);
            foreach (var (key, value) in HtmlAttributes)
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute(key, value);
            }
        }
```

Then in your template, you can do:

```cs
@model string
<input asp-for="@Model" html-attributes="@((IDictionary<string, string>)ViewData["HtmlAttributes"])" />
```

Comment: Thanks but from what I can see this shows how to set the HtmlAttributes property of the editor tag helper. But I'd like to set the attributes of the input tag helper (inside the String editor template) from the HtmlAttributes property of the editor tag helper.

Comment: The same logic applies, create a new tag helper but instead of specifying the `editor` as the HtmlTargetElement, you'd specify the `input` element.

Comment: Thanks but this tag helper is the equivalent of Html.EditorFor. I'll update the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Exactly what are you asking? Because the answer I gave you will work for the editor-for as well as the input - or any other element for that matter.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the question is a more of a Razor question and more about how to add all the attributes from a dictionary to a tag helper. The edited answer might be the solution but it does mean I'll have to create my own tag helpers for any one I pass my HTML attributes to.